# Where does the word 'gambit' come from?

Tags: opening, history, terminology

According to Merriam Webster's Dictionary, a gambit is

> a chess opening in which a player risks one or more pawns or a minor piece to gain an advantage in position.

But I was wondering, why do we use the word 'gambit'? Where does it come from? How we came to use it?

Comment: It's a play on words. When your position is hopelessly lost you violently overturn the board, throwing pieces all around the room, and yell "Dodd Gambit!".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name ['gambit'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit) was coined in the *16th century* already by [Ruy López](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruy_L%C3%B3pez_de_Segura). He derived it from the old Italian expression

> dare il gambetto

(literally: 'to give the leg'). It means 'to trip (someone) over' - gambits were often used in attempt to win a game quickly.

Comment: Great answer. The word meaning is quite unexpected.